# Cant figure out why Waypoints sticky is not working

Tags: css, sticky

I've tried using waypoints sticky feature, but it just refuses to work. Ditto with the other waypoint features e.g.when a particular element hits the top of the viewport. There is no action at all!
Here is my code for the sticky feature. The first paragraph should "sticky" on top of the viewport and rest should scroll naturally:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    .introCap{
    font-size: 10em;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
  <p id="introCap1"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. </p>
        <p class="introCap"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. </p>
        <p class="introCap"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. </p>
        <p class="introCap"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. </p>
        <p class="introCap"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. </p>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="waypoints.min.js"></script>
<script src="waypoints-sticky.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#introCap1').waypoint('sticky');
});
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

**FIDDLE**: http://jsfiddle.net/4SYdB/1/

Answer (score 0):

First of all include the shortcut script; [read more here](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/shortcuts/sticky-elements/)..  Check the **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4SYdB/1/)**.

```
<script src="/path/to/waypoints-sticky.min.js"></script>
<script src="waypoints.min.js"></script>
```

If still won't work Try to add a class `.stuck` . Adds a class to the sticky element when the user reaches it. By default, when the element reaches the top of the viewport it gains the stuck class.

**In HTML add the class `stuck`**

```
<p id="introCap1" class="stuck">Sticky Header </p>
```

**`CSS`**

```
.stuck{
    position:fixed; 
    top:0;
    left:0;
    margin:0;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #6a6272;
    color: #eae2f2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay managed to reverse engineer the example code provided on their site. The catch was adding a `#introCap1.stuck` definition in css as follows:

```
#introCap1.stuck{
    position:fixed; 
    top:0;
}
```